# How to push an application to the ibm cloud?

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have an application that runs on my local pc and is connected to mongoDB what's also installed on my pc. Now I want to run this application in IBM Cloud. Therefore I added mongoDB to my services in IBM Cloud and tried to push my application like in this [example](https://cloud.ibm.com/services/databases-for-mongodb/crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-de:a%2F159dd16918d84106bfe7080d5706d8e0:0ec9fb95-982f-4a9a-a130-305299dea1da::?paneId=gettingStarted).

My manifest.yml looks like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: clouddatabases-mongodb-nodejs
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  routes:
  - route: example-mongo-helloworld-nodejs.eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud
  memory:  128M
  services:
   - mymongoDB
```

My command prompt looks like this after I try to push my app in the cloud with "ibmcloud cf push clouddatabases-mongodb-nodejs -p C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx\app-folder":

[command prompt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ2Sy.jpg)

[command prompt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmDtJ.png)

Comment: Says you don't have a `package.json`

Comment: Do I really need it or ist package.json only nice to have?

Comment: `package.json` specifies modules/dependencies needed for your application to run such as `mongodb`. It also specifies scripts for starting your application. So yes, if your application uses any node modules then you must have a `package.json`

Comment: When you `npm install` modules, you should use `--save` option to write it to `package.json` as a dependency. Then, when you deploy, `npm install` will be ran to install all the dependencies listed in `package.json`. Then it will probably call `npm start` command, which you can specify in `package.json` as well.

Comment: I'll also add that running `npm init` will generate `package.json` for you, then you can install and save dependencies.